# Can you verify an EIP712 signature using ethers/web3?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, signature, ecdsa, eip712

Is it possible to verify EIP712 signature using ethersjs or web3js? or the standard will always be to verified it on-chain? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ethers.utils.verifyTypedData` as documented [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/signing-key/#utils-verifyTypedData) and you can find an example [here](https://github.com/centrehq/verite/blob/main/packages/verite/test/lib/verifier/result.test.ts#L46)